# Flutter - Health package not loading STEP data

Tags: flutter, google-fit, google-fit-api, flutter-health

I've used health-3.0.3 in my flutter application to get the Google fit data. I'm able to get every data other than STEP-data which shows zero always.

You can refer to the health package here
[Health 3.0.3 Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/health/example)

This is the code block to access the STEP datatype in my application

```
List<HealthDataType> types = [
      HealthDataType.STEPS,
      HealthDataType.WEIGHT,
      //HealthDataType.HEIGHT,
    ];

    setState(() => _state = AppState.FETCHING_DATA);

    /// You MUST request access to the data types before reading them
    bool accessWasGranted = await health.requestAuthorization(types);

    double steps = 0;

    if (accessWasGranted) {
      try {
        /// Fetch new data
        List<HealthDataPoint> healthData =
            await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(startDate, endDate, types);

        /// Save all the new data points
        _healthDataList.addAll(healthData);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Caught exception in getHealthDataFromTypes: $e");
      }

      /// Filter out duplicates
      _healthDataList = HealthFactory.removeDuplicates(_healthDataList);

      /// Print the results
      _healthDataList.forEach((x) {
        print("Data point: $x");
        steps += (x.value as double);
      });

      print("Steps: $steps");
```

You can refer to the full code under the examples tab in the given link. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you confirmed the accessWasGranted is true using debug mode and the step count is shown on GoogleFit App correctly?

Comment: accessWasGranted  always false any update

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yeah accessWasGranted is set to true and step data is showing correctly on Google fit

Comment: @WaiKyaw No not yet

Comment: @GaneshCKM I've switched to version health:3.0.4 and it is working

Comment: Issue solved Go to this link [Authorization Not Granted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562594/16026565)

Comment: Issue Solved Go to this link [Authorization Not Granted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562594/16026565)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**health: 3.0.4** is more stable, when I'm writing this answer.

From Android 10. you have to add `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` for getting STEP Count permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

And then using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) ask for permission.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final permissionStatus = Permission.activityRecognition.request();
  if (await permissionStatus.isDenied ||
      await permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    showToast(
        'activityRecognition permission required to fetch your steps count');
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer helped a ton, thanks.