# Using Google fit API in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-health, google-healthcare-api

I need my app to read step count from Google Fit. I'm using health 3.05 package. For now I copied the example code to see if it works and unfortunately it's not. Of course I did every step from this packge readme. I set up OAuth2 Client ID, I changed gradle.properties as they shown and in AndroidManifest.xml I put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>`  . However after running app I don't get any permission window and when I click the button to get data I got an error "Authorization not granted" in console. What should I do? Thanks

Here is my code that I copied form package example:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:health/health.dart';

class DailyStepsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DailyStepsScreenState createState() => _DailyStepsScreenState();
}

enum AppState {
  DATA_NOT_FETCHED,
  FETCHING_DATA,
  DATA_READY,
  NO_DATA,
  AUTH_NOT_GRANTED
}

class _DailyStepsScreenState extends State<DailyStepsScreen> {
  List<HealthDataPoint> _healthDataList = [];
  AppState _state = AppState.DATA_NOT_FETCHED;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    /// Get everything from midnight until now
    DateTime startDate = DateTime(2020, 11, 07, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime(2025, 11, 07, 23, 59, 59);

    HealthFactory health = HealthFactory();

    /// Define the types to get.
    List<HealthDataType> types = [
      HealthDataType.STEPS,
      HealthDataType.WEIGHT,
      HealthDataType.HEIGHT,
      HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE,
      HealthDataType.DISTANCE_WALKING_RUNNING,
    ];

    setState(() => _state = AppState.FETCHING_DATA);

    /// You MUST request access to the data types before reading them
    bool accessWasGranted = await health.requestAuthorization(types);

    int steps = 0;

    if (accessWasGranted) {
      try {
        /// Fetch new data
        List<HealthDataPoint> healthData =
        await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(startDate, endDate, types);

        /// Save all the new data points
        _healthDataList.addAll(healthData);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Caught exception in getHealthDataFromTypes: $e");
      }

      /// Filter out duplicates
      _healthDataList = HealthFactory.removeDuplicates(_healthDataList);

      /// Print the results
      _healthDataList.forEach((x) {
        print("Data point: $x");
        steps += x.value.round();
      });

      print("Steps: $steps");

      /// Update the UI to display the results
      setState(() {
        _state =
        _healthDataList.isEmpty ? AppState.NO_DATA : AppState.DATA_READY;
      });
    } else {
      print("Authorization not granted");
      setState(() => _state = AppState.DATA_NOT_FETCHED);
    }
  }

  Widget _contentFetchingData() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 10,
            )),
        Text('Fetching data...')
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _contentDataReady() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _healthDataList.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          HealthDataPoint p = _healthDataList[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("${p.typeString}: ${p.value}"),
            trailing: Text('${p.unitString}'),
            subtitle: Text('${p.dateFrom} - ${p.dateTo}'),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _contentNoData() {
    return Text('No Data to show');
  }

  Widget _contentNotFetched() {
    return Text('Press the download button to fetch data');
  }

  Widget _authorizationNotGranted() {
    return Text('''Authorization not given.
        For Android please check your OAUTH2 client ID is correct in Google Developer Console.
         For iOS check your permissions in Apple Health.''');
  }

  Widget _content() {
    if (_state == AppState.DATA_READY)
      return _contentDataReady();
    else if (_state == AppState.NO_DATA)
      return _contentNoData();
    else if (_state == AppState.FETCHING_DATA)
      return _contentFetchingData();
    else if (_state == AppState.AUTH_NOT_GRANTED)
      return _authorizationNotGranted();

    return _contentNotFetched();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
                onPressed: () {
                  fetchData();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: _content(),
          )
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: same problem here

Comment: same here! Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: Same problem...

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1** use `health: 3.0.4`

**Step 2** do proper set up for OAuth2 Client ID, download new google-service.json

**Step 3** From Android 10. you have to add `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` for getting STEP Count permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

**Step 4** And then using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) ask for permission.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final permissionStatus = Permission.activityRecognition.request();
  if (await permissionStatus.isDenied ||
      await permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    showToast(
        'activityRecognition permission required to fetch your steps count');
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Ganesh please check this out.

Comment: About step 2, where should I get this google-service.json? I am new to Android. I have configured the consent screen and Oauth client id, and I downloaded the client_secret_*.json file. But I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY GOT THIS ISSUE SOLVED!!

So the problem doesn't lie in the version I am using 3.4.0 but still got the problem solved

> **Authorization not granted. And stuck in loading screen**

[Stuck in authorization request screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKmoJ.png)

When you create your OAuth 2.0 consent screen try to add at least 2 email addresses to the TEST USER section and make sure to login from that emails.

[Add 2 email addresses in Test User](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)

After that make sure to verify your application from Google, it will work until you test your app once you release the application, it will not work

[Verify Your Application from Google](https://developers.google.com/fit/verification)

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWa1O.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 use health: 3.0.4

Step 2 Add permission function

Step 3 Start your function inside of initstate