# Google Fit Oauth stuck in loading

Tags: flutter, dart, google-oauth, google-fit

I'm using Google Fit in my app to read Steps data. I've verified my app from Google Console's Oauth consent screen section for the scopes I'm requesting. Some of the users still see infinite loading on Google Oauth.

The health package I'm using: https://github.com/metaflowltd/flutter_health_fit

I've also used this package but same result: https://pub.dev/packages/health

[image]
[image]

Comment: Refer to this, here I have given a detailed answer on it [Stuck in Authorization page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432179/using-google-fit-api-in-flutter/70562594#70562594)

Comment: Refer this I have given a detailed answer on this [Authorization not Granted, stuck in loading screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432179/using-google-fit-api-in-flutter/70562594#70562594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed by removing the line from the kotlin code, which builds the permission with an extra scope which is not verified for my app.

**brief info about the issue I've faced:**

If you don't verify your scopes, google fit's oauth page stuck in loading. you may not notice when your app is in testing but if you are in production, that's the case pretty much.
I spent 2 months to verify fitness.activity.read scope and that's the only thing I need for my app. Currently this library also adds fitness.body.read request on getFitnessOptions method. I removed that line on [my fork](https://github.com/mirkancal/flutter_health_fit/commit/f99ad40a0951c385e65a69c63a505b28ed3447af#diff-52e47a8fa1afc3fe028475445f111f9df59ad0f6b15b627473f8fe781200da2aL584) and solved the problem.